# How do I calculate the euclidean distance to the nearest neighbour for each coordinates pair in meters in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, coordinates, nearest-neighbor, haversine

I have a dataframe like this

| index | place id | var_lat_fact | var_lon_fact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 167312091448 | 5.6679820000 | -0.0144950000 |
| 1 | 167312091448 | 5.6686320000 | -0.0157910000 |
| 2 | 167312091448 | 5.6653530000 | -0.0181980000 |
| 3 | 167312091448 | 5.6700970000 | -0.0191400000 |
| 4 | 167312091448 | 5.6689810000 | -0.0104040000 |

For each coordinates pair (lat, lon) I'd like to calculate the euclidean distance to the nearest neighbour within the dataframe. So each point gets a metric in the additional column (say, nearest_neighbour_dist) indicating that distance in meters.

Something like this

| index | place id | var_lat_fact | var_lon_fact | nearest_neighbour_dist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 167312091448 | 5.6679820000 | -0.0144950000 | 160.588370 |
| 1 | 167312091448 | 5.6686320000 | -0.0157910000 | 160.588370 |
| 2 | 167312091448 | 5.6653530000 | -0.0181980000 | 451.525301 |
| 3 | 167312091448 | 5.6700970000 | -0.0191400000 | 404.794908 |
| 4 | 167312091448 | 5.6689810000 | -0.0104040000 | 466.104453 |

Just can't get my head around this...
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Images are not reproducible, please provide a [mre] (and the matching expected output)

Comment: You sure you need euclidean distance from lat and long?

Comment: An euclidean distance will be incorrect. You should use a [haversine distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Comment: Rhumb distance, geodesic distance, haversine distance are the distances you need and not euclidean. Especially the geodesic distance. haversine computes distance on a sphere while geodesic computes distance on an ellipsoid. With the control of a and b, geodesic is a generalization of haversine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sklearn's [`NearestNeighbors`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from numpy import deg2rad

# set up the nearest neighbors
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, metric='haversine')
data = deg2rad(df[['var_lat_fact', 'var_lon_fact']])
neigh.fit(data)

# find the closest two points
# the closest distance is self, the second one is the closest non-self
df['nearest_neighbour_dist'] = (neigh.kneighbors(data,
                                                 n_neighbors=2, return_distance=True
                                                )[0][:, -1]
                                *6371*1000
                               )
```

Output:

```
   index      place_id  var_lat_fact  var_lon_fact  nearest_neighbour_dist
0      0  167312091448      5.667982     -0.014495              160.588370
1      1  167312091448      5.668632     -0.015791              160.588370
2      2  167312091448      5.665353     -0.018198              451.525301
3      3  167312091448      5.670097     -0.019140              404.794908
4      4  167312091448      5.668981     -0.010404              466.104453
```

##### Points on a map

I wanted to double check the validity of the computations

1 -> 2 (index 0-> 1 in your data) is indeed about 160.6 meters

[image]

Comment: @Dmitri you're welcome. You might want to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77900654/edit) your question to fix the output with the correct distances.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing, you can't compute euclidean distances in the Geographic Coordinate System (longitude and latitude). You need to convert these points to Cartesian Coordinates. Also, are you sure you're looking for the Euclidean distance? Something like the Geodesic distance seems more natural for this problem. The Euclidean distance will give you the distance "through" the earth, while the Geodesic will give you the distance as if you were walking over the curvature of the earth.

## Distance to Nearest Neighbor with Euclidean Distance

1. Convert to Euclidean coordinates

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('path_to_your_csv.csv')

earth_radius = 6371000
df['x'] = earth_radius * np.cos(df['var_lat_fact']) * np.cos(df['var_lon_fact'])
df['y'] = earth_radius * np.cos(df['var_lat_fact']) * np.sin(df['var_lon_fact'])
df['z'] = earth_radius * np.sin(df['var_lat_fact'])
```

2. Compute the distance between all the points

```py
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

# Create a matrix of all points
points = df[['x', 'y', 'z']].to_numpy()

# Compute the distance matrix
dist_matrix = distance_matrix(points, points)

# Set the diagonal to infinity to ignore zero distance to self
np.fill_diagonal(dist_matrix, np.inf)

# Find the minimum distance for each point
df['nearest_neighbor_dist'] = np.min(dist_matrix, axis=1)

# Drop the Cartesian coordinates as they are no longer needed
df = df.drop(['x', 'y', 'z'], axis=1)
```

3. The `df['nearest_neighbor_dist']` now contains the Euclidean distance to the nearest neighbor.

## Distance to Nearest Neighbor with Geodesic Distance

1. Compute the nearest neighbor distance to each point:

```py
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import geodesic

# Convert the latitude and longitude from your DataFrame to a list of (lat, lon) tuples
coordinates = list(zip(df['var_lat_fact'], df['var_lon_fact']))

# Initialize a list to hold the nearest neighbor distances
nearest_neighbor_dists = []

# Calculate the geodesic distance from each point to every other point
for i in range(len(coordinates)):
    distances = [geodesic(coordinates[i], coordinates[j]).meters for j in range(len(coordinates)) if i != j]
    # Keep the smallest one
    nearest_neighbor_dists.append(min(distances))
```

2. The `df[nearest_neighbor_dist]` column now contains the distance to the nearest neighbor in geodesic distance.

```py
df['nearest_neighbor_dist'] = nearest_neighbor_dists
```

Comment: Thank you, Michael, for offering such a detailed solution. Really appreciate that! I tried this one as well, but the solution written by mozway works way faster.